# Uploading a file over HTTP and reading the result in C#

Tags: c#, http, upload, response

The title of this question should be self explanatory, but basically I have this code (working)

```
        progfrm = new progressform();
        System.Net.WebClient ahwebclient = new System.Net.WebClient();
        progfrm.Show();
        ahwebclient.UploadProgressChanged += new System.Net.UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(ahwebclient_UploadProgressChanged);
        ahwebclient.UploadFileCompleted += new System.Net.UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(ahwebclient_UploadFileCompleted);
        ahwebclient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("http://upload.anyhub.net/bin/demovu_upload.php"), "C:/install.exe");
        while (ahwebclient.IsBusy)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

How would I read this result of this request once it is completed?

Comment: What is in your `ahwebclient_UploadFileCompleted` event handler method?

Comment: void ahwebclient_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, System.Net.UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            progfrm.Close();
            progfrm.Dispose();
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it from the Result property of UploadFileCompletedEventArgs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.uploadfilecompletedeventargs_members(VS.80).aspx).  You already have a UploadFileCompletedEventHandler, so you just need to modify the method implementing that delegate,